# Transforming a layer in Photoshop creates a copy of the layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm a regular user of Photoshop since the CS3 times, and this is the problem that haunts me from the beginning, regardless of the PS version, and the platform - when I do a transformation on a layer (Scale, Skew, Distort, Warp... but not Rotate), **sometimes** a copy of the layer is created and my transformation is done on that copy, not on the original layer. I say "sometimes" because I can't find any regularity in this behavior, sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't.

Weird thing is, I can't find anything about it on the Internet, like it's happening to no one but me. Anybody knows why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

If you press command-option-T to initiate the transform, instead of just command-T, it’ll duplicate the layer, layers, group or shape selected.

It sounds like that might be what’s happening?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because it's not happening only when I use Free Transform, but for Scale, Warp and other tools under Edit->Transform (except for Rotate and Flip). Usually, I use alt(option)-e-a-/tool shotcut/, but it's the same when I navigate to those tools with a mouse.

Comment: Hmm. Time to trash your preferences and see if that helps?

Comment: Well, the reason I posted this question now is that I recently installed PS CS6 on a freshly installed Win7, and the only two things I change in preferences  are units and scratch disk (I'm not saving/loading my old preferences). But who knows, it could be the reason, it's worth trying. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pressing **Shift+Ctrl+H** after you make your shape then hit Ctrl+T (or Alt+Ctrl+T) to transform your shape will create transformed object on a new layer; otherwise it will be on the original layer and a copy of the layet will not be created.